# Можно ли быстро перенести приложение написанное на java на Andriod?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть приложение на Java. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ быстро и легко адаптировать приложение для Android?

Comment: Зависит от технологий, которые Вы использовали и графического интерфейса. Переделывать надо будет только графический интерфейс, если Вы правильно приложение написали. Некоторые вещи просто не получится сделать. Как пример - БД MySql на андроиде Вы не заведете.

Comment: Попробуйте адаптировать код используя Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

Вы не можите просто конвертировать java проект в android  проект. Если вы хотите android  приложение то вам нужно спроектировать и построить заново android приложение пытаясь переиспользовать так много кода насколько это возможно из java кода. В дополнении вам необходимо учесть, что мобильное приложение распологает меньшим количеством ресурсом в сравнении с компьютером